# How to show the correct content when clicked the same class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I hope any of you can give me some help. As you can see I have a list and appended all list in a table. Now, I added listeners to show the divs named below. Since all the divs have the same class now, the show() function is not working. Does anyone know how to get it showing the one I clicked?

Thanks xxx
Li.

PS: I tried to use closest, but it does not go anywhere.

```
    $('.bundle-main').append('<ul class="item-content clearfix">\
                        <li class="td td-chk">\
                          <div class="cart-checkbox ">\
                            <input class="check" id="J_CheckBox_170037950254" name="items[]" value="170037950254" type="checkbox">\
                            <label for="J_CheckBox_170037950254"></label>\
                          </div>\
                        </li>\
                       <li class="td td-info">\
                        <div class="item-props item-props-can">\
                            <span class="sku-line">'+data[0].productname+'</span>\
                             <span tabindex="0" class="btn-edit-sku theme-login" >edit</span>\
                               <i class="theme-login am-icon-sort-desc"></i>\
                         </div>\
                       </li>\    
                      <div class="theme-popover-mask">
                       <div class="theme-popover">\
                         <div class="theme-span">
                         </div>\
                        </div>\
                      </div>\
                    </ul>');
var $ww = $(window).width();
        $('.theme-login').click(function() {

                $(document.body).css("position","fixed");



                $(this).addClass("selected");
                $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
                var to=$(this).prev().offset().top+30;
                var th=$(this).offset().top;
                var tl=$(this).offset().left-200;

                $('.theme-span').show();                
                $('.theme-popover-mask').show();
                $('.theme-popover-mask').height($(document).height());
                $('.theme-popover').slideDown(200);

   if ($ww>640){
                $('.theme-popover').css("top",th);
                $('.theme-popover').css("left",tl);
                $('.theme-popover-mask').hide();
}
```

Comment: I don't see `theme-login` in the HTML you're adding. How is it related to the elements that should be shown by clicking on it?

Comment: You have a bunch of `/` at the ends of lines that should be  `\ `

Comment: Hi Barmar, I have updated it. The situation is I have appended the list dynamically and I have a section where it is clickable to allow user to see extra information. However, I do not know how to show the exact one.

Comment: The tags don't match, you have two `</div>` at the end that don't have matching `<div>`

Comment: `$(this).closest(".item-content").find(".theme-span")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use DOM traversal to find the `.theme-span`, `.theme-popover-mask`, and `.theme-popover` elements that are in the same `item-content` UL as the one you clicked on:

```
var ul = $(this).closest(".item-content");
var span = ul.find(".theme-span");
var popover_mask = ul.find(".theme-popover-mask");
var popover = ul.find(".popover");
```

You can't use `.closest` by itself, because it just searches the containing elements.